# Problems with Vim after upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, vim, make

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 using `do-release-upgrade`, facing no problems whatsoever. I had Vim installed in my system (build from source). But now, when I try to run Vim, I get this error:

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I always build Vim from source, following this instructions: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source . I've removed my old installation and build it again, and the same error happened. Any tips on how to proceed to make Vim works?

EDIT 1: I ran `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v` and the output was that: https://pastebin.com/dAcGdVWE

Comment: Apart from installing the default vim? What does "dpkg -S libperl.so" return?

Comment: @AndreasF I didn't try to install vim from Ubuntu official repos yet. `dpkg -S libperl.so` returns that: 
`libperl5.30:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30.0`
`libperl5.30:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30`
`libperl-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so`
`libperl5.30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30`
`libperl5.30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try running

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

What it will do (From ldconfig man page):

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib and /usr/lib). The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.

Solution taken form [this](https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/) article by itsfoss

EDIT-1:You can use ldconfig to list all installed libraries by running
`/sbin/ldconfig -v -N`. If libperl.so.5.28 is not listed try:

From the output on pastebin it seems that you have libperl.so.5.30 wheras the error shows it is searching for libperl.so.5.28. Maybe try sym-linking libperl.so.5.30 to libperl.so.5.28 in the directory where libperl.so.5.30 exists.

```
cd /path/where/libperl.so.5.30/exists
ln -s libperl.so.5.30 libperl.so.5.28
```

Comment: I did. It showed some missing paths and executed some operations. When I tried to open Vim, the same error appeared. I'm editing the question to put the complete log of this command.

Comment: Wow, you got this! After creating the symlink in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` as you suggested above, it asked in the same way for another library, `libpython3.7m.so.1.0`. This library was located in the same folder, I checked that I have another version in the pastebin and did the same. It asked for another one. I did the same, and now Vim works again! It give some errors when it starts, but running smooth until now!

Comment: The symlink fixed for me too. The command was `sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.30 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.28`.